# I cant build my created app in android studio 2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

My project in android studio 2.1.1. I'm unable to build it because of JDK error ..can someone help me please I can send them the file project if its okay and try to look it up. I tried to build it but JDK is where the error is. I really need it coz its my final project.

This is the project i hope you can check it out
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1teZp43k8xm-xVNFVdwuNyLAIemMX6JKr/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Welcome to SO, please attach code and error in the question. Without these it is difficult to help you.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1teZp43k8xm-xVNFVdwuNyLAIemMX6JKr/view?usp=drivesdk              this is my project i hope you can check it out

Comment: Is there any specific error message when building? This would be helpful to know because digging through the entire project might be very time-consuming :D

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.